# What is the relationship between the primary menu links and secondary menu links in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6

I tried another CMS which is Drupal and as I was having a walkthrough on the basics of `Drupal 6`, I met the primary and secondary menu links. I have tried creating both and I wonder what could be their relation or connection. Can anybody inform me as brief and concise as possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As briefly as possible:
You have 2 choises:

1. The primary links and the secondary links are completely different menus, with no relation whatsoever
2. You can also set the secondary link source to 'primary links' in the menu settings. This will have as effect that the children of primary links, set in the primary link menu, will be displayed in this secondary menu.

For example, if you have:

- A

  - A.1
  - A.2
- B

  - B.1

In the first 'choice', your primary link menu will contain all these links. But in the second choice, your primary link menu will contain A and B, and the secondary will contain A.1 and A.2 or B.1, depening on the primary link selection (A or B).

This 10-minute video covers these both options: http://www.lullabot.com/videos/using-secondary-menus